# How to use literal type as a service constructor parameter in NestJS

Tags: dependency-injection, service, nestjs

I have a literal type as a constructor parameter on my service:

```
export type MyType = 'val1' | 'val2';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  myType: MyType;
  constructor(private appService: AppService, private myType: MyType = 'val2') {
    this.myType = myType;
  }
}
```

I have an error on build time

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the MyService (AppService, ?). Please make sure that the argument String at index [1] is available in the AppModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If String is a provider, is it part of the current AppModule?
- If String is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within AppModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing String */ ]
  })
```

How would you fix that?

that is my AppModule:

```
@Module({
  imports: [HttpModule],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService, MyService, HttpClient],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Are you providing anything for Nest to inject for `MyType` in your module file?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Just updated the question with my `AppModule`

Answer (score 5):

With NestJS, you need to provide constructor arguments via `providers`. Nest uses `classes` usually to know what injection token to work with, as classes persist in both Typescript and JavaScript. However, you can use the `@Inject()` decorator with your own injection token and custom value to ensure that Nest injects the value properly. This will look something like this:

```js
@Module({
  providers: [
    MyService,
    {
      provide: 'MyToken', // this can be a symbol or a string
      useValue: 'val2',
    }
    AppService,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

```js
export type MyType = 'val1' | 'val2';
@Injectable()
export class MyService {


  constructor(
    private appService: AppService,
    // this token MUST match exactly to the one in the `provide` property of the custom provider
    @Inject('MyToken') private myType: MyType
  ) {}
}
```

If you want to add other dependencies, just make sure they are available to the module.

The other option is to mark `myType` as `@Optional()` which will allow Nest to bypass the injection if it is unresolvable, then you can easily still use the default value as you were before

Comment: as you can see I have default value `private myType: MyType = 'val2'` that can be overwritten by caller in runtime. So how would you be able to overwrite that value in runtime using tokens?

Comment: How do you plan on calling `MyService` at runtime? Are you going to be letting Nest handle it or are you planning on making the instances on your own?

Comment: As you can see I am providing `MyService` in  `AppModule` so I am not instantiating that manually

Comment: So how do yo plan on changing the value for `MyType`? WHat would it change based on? It would be possible to do it using `useFactory` instead of `useValue` where you provide a function to determine the value to be provided, but I can't show an example without knowing _how_ you plan to decide what value should be provided.

Comment: Yeah it is a good question, I think I might stick with `provide -> value` then however I wonder how would you approach that with factories and what is the difference using provide vs factories?

Comment: Factories would allow you to inject other services or providers and then allow you to return new values based on what's input. I've got a couple examples [like here](https://github.com/jmcdo29/ogma/blob/monorepo/packages/nestjs-module/src/ogma-core.module.ts#L46), [and here](https://github.com/jmcdo29/zeldaPlay/blob/master/apps/api/src/app/app.module.ts#L23) (`useClass` is very similar to `useFactory`, so they can be treated the same)